# Programatically change selected item in Outlook

Tags: vba, outlook

I'm trying to write a piece of code that takes a user-selected list of items (typically mailitems) from the active explorer, performs some action on them (e.g. setting the value of a custom field), then - when complete - selects the next item in the explorer window and ends execution there.

- I have no problem identifying the selected list of items
- I have no problem looping through the selected items and performing required actions on each
- But I cannot, for the life of me, figure out how to programatically select the *next* item in the explorer window upon completing the above process (keeping in mind, the next item is **NOT** in the list of user-selected items.

Example ...

- Inbox has 10 items
- User selects items 1, 4 and 7
- Code identifies items 1, 4 and 7 as the active selection
- Code performs an action on items 1, 4 and 7

--> Upon completion, I want item #8 to be selected

Is this possible ???

The wrinkle, and why I *can't* just use a SendKeys "{DOWN}" statement at the end: the active view is grouped by a custom field (... call it a flag, for ease of reference) - where flag=false show up at the top of the screen in group #1, and flag=true show up in group #2 at the bottom of the screen. It's a way of relegating mailitems to a "basement" of sorts, without deleting them or having to move them to some other folder. They stay in the inbox, but get grouped separately, out of sight.

The actions being performed on items 1, 4 and 7 consist of setting the flag to TRUE, thereby causing the items to disappear from the upper portion of the screen, and moving to the lower part of the screen (i.e. in group #2). This all works great.

... until the code reaches the final item in the selection, and again does what it needs to do, and ends ... but at this point the active/selected mailitem that is displayed in the explorer window is the same last mailitem (#7). So the user is now seeing a mailitem way down the inbox in group #2. In other words, the user is now in the basement of the inbox, not at the top, because Outlook is displaying the last mailitem in the selection, which has been moved to the basement by the code.

I want the code to change the active/selected mailitem to be #8 (which still has a value of FALSE for that custom field I'm setting), so that upon completing code execution, the screen position remains where it was when the code was executed.

The only thing I've managed to do is apply a SendKeys "{HOME}" at the end, so at least the user's view continues to show the mailitems in group #1 ... but not the right mailitem.

I'm really stumped here.

Any help would be appreciated.

NB> My thought process was, at the time of initiating the code, to identify the last mailitem in the selection (... either by index # or by EntryID) - which I can do easy enough - but then somehow finding a way to i) locate the NEXT mailitem immediately following it, and storing this reference, and then ii) upon completing the code, getting outlook to select the mailitem with the reference ID I saved. I can't figure out how to do this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If received time is in some order you could use that to determine the next item to select.

The process could look like this.

```
selCount = ActiveExplorer.Selection.Count

' Assumes you select downwards not randomly
minRecTime = ActiveExplorer.Selection(selCount).ReceivedTime
```

Once the items are moved loop downward through the items.

```
currRecTime = currFolder.items(i).ReceivedTime

If currRecTime < minRecTime Then

    Exit For

End If
```

Now you have a position with "i".

Remember to run from a button not the VB editor to see SendKeys work.

```
SendKeys "{HOME}"

For j = 1 To i - 1

    SendKeys "{DOWN}"

Next j
```